# How to transfer table from one database to another database?

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, linkedin-api, rdbms

I was working on Azure Data Studio. By mistake I created a table in the system administrator's database. I want to transfer it to another database which is created by me. How can I transfer that table?

Comment: Use SSMS.  https://blog.atwork.at/post/How-to-copy-table-data-between-Azure-SQL-Databases

Comment: Or you also can use navicat. https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

With Azure Data Studio, we can't transfer the table to another database directly. Azure SQL database also doesn't support USE statement. And Azure Data Studio doesn't support import or export jobs. The only way are that:

1. Create the table with data again in user DB again an then delete is
   in  System administration's database
2. [Elastic query(CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE,EXTERNAL TABLE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical) to cross database query the table data in System
   administration's database, and then import it to your user DB.

I tested in Azure Data Studio and it works well. Since you can create table in System administration's database, I think you have enough permission to do this operations.

If you can use SSMS, the could be much easier and there are many ways can achieve it. For example:

1. Ref the blog:
   https://blog.atwork.at/post/How-to-copy-table-data-between-Azure-SQL-Databases
   @Json Pan provide in comment.
2. Export the table into a csv file and then import to user DB.
3. You also can use Elastic query.

Just choose the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SQL Server Import extension` ([see ms documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-server-import-extension?view=sql-server-ver16#install-the-sql-server-import-extension)).

1. first **export the existing table** f.e.: to csv with

- Select the data of the table
- export as csv to a local directory

2. Import it on the target DB (table)

- right click DB in Connections tab - `Import wizard`

Answer (score 0):

In this case of need one can simply copy output and manually insert it in destinations.

For that I use this template with two statements one in source one in destination DB.

```
--Open source 

declare @table nvarchar(100) = 'TableName'

declare @select nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT CONCAT(''(''';

select @select = 
case when DATA_TYPE in     ('nvarchar','nchar','varchar','char','datetime','datetime2','time','date')
then CONCAT(@select, ',CASE WHEN ', COLUMN_NAME, ' IS NULL THEN ''NULL'' ELSE CONCAT('''''''', ', COLUMN_NAME, ','''''''') END,'',''')
else CONCAT(@select, ',CASE WHEN ', COLUMN_NAME, ' IS NULL THEN ''NULL'' ELSE ', COLUMN_NAME ,' END,'',''')
end
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = @table
set @select = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@select, 1, LEN(@select)-2) ,'),'') FROM ', @table)

select @select
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @select

--Copy output

--Open destination 

declare @table nvarchar(100) = 'TableName'

declare @insert nvarchar(max) = CONCAT('insert into ', @table, ' (')

select  @insert = CONCAT(@insert, COLUMN_NAME, ',')
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = @table
set @insert = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@insert, 1, LEN(@insert)-1) ,') values')

select @insert
```